# Syntax error when using WITH...AS statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I'm inserting data into table and I want to get last id which will be later used for another query.

Here is table structure and query [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1435f2/5)

I'm receiving this error

> ERROR: syntax error at end of input Position: 890

What could be wrong in insert statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my apologies i linked wrong fiddle

Comment: Note that questions should be self-contained, so please [edit] your question and include the code that generates the error as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: I fixed the query in your link, but post it here so i can answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all DBMS, when you declare a "view" using the *with ... as ()* syntax, you are expected to use it immediately. If you try to execute only the *with ... as ()* construct, you will get an error and PostgreSQL will wait for you to complete the query.

You have two options: either remove the "with" construct and obtain the result of your "returning" clause, or append a query to the "view" created through *with ... as ()* to read its contents, as follows:

```
with app as (
 INSERT INTO public.tag 
 (class, name, value_type, history_type, persistent_history_limit_type,persistent_history_size, cache_size, unity, threshold_group, threshold, threshold_saving_option, threshold_time, uses_linear_regression, linear_regression_cluster_period, linear_regression_number_of_clusters, enum_mapping, site_id, as_id, use_bit_info, tag_bit, writing_only, active, detail, scanner_id, top_output, top_input, bottom_input, bottom_output, primary_rated, transducer_rated, secondary_rated, raw_upper_range, invert, scaling_type, relative_offset, absolute_offset)
 VALUES
 ('TAG', 'PLCOFFLINEx', 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, '', 'System', 1.0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) RETURNING oid as lastid
)
 select * from app
```

From Doc:

> ... and the WITH clause itself is attached to a primary statement that can also be a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE

I hope this helps!

Comment: "*you are expected to use it immediately.*" - that's not only the case in Postgres. That's the way common table expressions work. In all DBMS

Answer (score 1):

[sql-fiddle](https://%20http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1435f2/24)

```
with lastinsert AS (
INSERT INTO public.tag ("class", "name", value_type, history_type, persistent_history_limit_type, persistent_history_size, cache_size, unity, threshold_group, threshold, threshold_saving_option, threshold_time, uses_linear_regression, linear_regression_cluster_period, linear_regression_number_of_clusters, enum_mapping, site_id, as_id, use_bit_info, tag_bit, writing_only, active, detail, scanner_id, top_output, top_input, bottom_input, bottom_output, primary_rated, transducer_rated, secondary_rated, raw_upper_range, invert, scaling_type, relative_offset, absolute_offset)
VALUES('TAG', 'PLCOFFLINEx', 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, '', 'System', 1.0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) 
 RETURNING oid)
 select oid as lastid from lastinsert
```